# How to count number of equal elements in a column of a matrix in a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

If A is a cell array which consists 100 50x50 matrix, and i want to count a specific element N from each column of each matrix in that cell array then how can I do it in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case, @Shai's answer is the way to go. However, since in this case all the matrices have the same size, you could save time by storing them in a 3D array instead of a cell array. That is, define array `A` of size 50x50x100, such that `A(:,:,1)` is the first matrix, `A(:,:,2)` is the second and so on. Then

```
count = squeeze(sum(A==N)).';
```

where `count(3,5)` is interpreted as in [@Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19344364/1714410).

Answer (score 1):

Use `cellfun`

```
>> count = cellfun( @(x) sum( x == N, 1 ), A, 'UniformOutput', 0 );
```

`count` is a cell array with 100 1-by-50 vectors: `count{3}(5)` is the number of elements equal to `N` in the 5th column of the thirs matrix in `A`